# Objective C writing unit test case for JSON parsing

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing

```
Code:

-(void) testParserMethod {

    NSDictionary *jsonDict= @{ @"title" : @"",
                              @"description" : @"",
                              @"imageHref" : @"",
                              };
    MyCountry *object = [[MyCountry alloc]init];

    XCTAssertEqual(object.title, jsonDict[@"title"]);
    XCTAssertEqual(object.description, jsonDict[@"description"]);
    XCTAssertEqual(object.ImageHref, jsonDict[@"imageHref"]);
}

@interface MyCountry : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *description;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *ImageHref;

- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)mycountryData;
@end




#import "MyCountry.h"

@implementation MyCountry
@synthesize title, description, ImageHref;
- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)mycountryData
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        title = mycountryData[@"title"];
        description = mycountryData[@"description"];
        ImageHref = mycountryData[@"imageHref"];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

I am trying to write parse test case for JSON response.I added all code what i tried.When i run the test case getting error as  "test failure: -[MyCountryTests testParserMethod] failed: ((object.title) equal to (jsonDict[@"title"])) failed: ("<00000000 00000000>") is not equal to ("<78215819 01000000>").Please somebody help me to fix this issue.any help will be appreicated.
".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test case is failing at this line:
`XCTAssertEqual(object.title, jsonDict[@"title"]);`

It's because your MyCountry object doesn't have its `title` set.

You initialize your object as : `MyCountry *object = [[MyCountry alloc]init];` 
 However, you should use your designated initializer which is: 
`- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)mycountryData`
 That way your object will have its title set.

Also instead of using `XCTAssertEqual();` to compare your Strings, you should use something like this:
`XCTAssertTrue([object.title isEqualToString:jsonDict[@"title"]],@"Strings are not equal %@ %@", object.title, jsonDict[@"title"]);`

Comment: MyCountry *object = [[MyCountry alloc]initWithDictionary:jsonDict]; is it correct?

Comment: It fixed.thanks for your answer.how to change my code check dictionary keys?

Comment: Can you be more specific please?  I edited my answer.

Comment: i  am trying to write test case validate JSON key against decalred key such   as title, description, imageHref.

Comment: i am writing test case to check JSON key

Comment: Do you mean to compare JSON keys with your object's property names?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165571/discussion-between-thecoderguy-and-karthi).